# Angular.copy keeps giving me the same object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an AngularJS application that manages badges. In the application is a form to set the badge # and the name of the person it is assigned to, etc. This gets stored in $scope.badge.

When the user submits the form, I want to add the new badge to a list of badges, which is displayed below the form.

Partial code looks like this:

```
var badge = angular.copy($scope.badge); // make a copy so we don't keep adding the same object
$scope.badgeList.push(badge);
```

The first time I run this code, it adds the badge as expected.
Any subsequent time I run this code, the next badge REPLACES the previous badge in the badgeList. In other words, if I add 5 badges, the badgeList still only has 1 object in it because it just keeps getting replaced.

I'm thinking that this may be happening because the same object keeps getting added? Maybe I'm wrong? I am using angular.copy to try and avoid that happening, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: something else is happening, so you need to show us more code.  https://jsfiddle.net/9vwvscug/

Comment: How is this relevant to angular.copy and `badge`? It's `badgeList` that doesn't behave as you expect. Please, provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.badgeList.push(($scope.badge);
console.log($scope.badgeList)
```

no need to use angular.copy since you are ultimately storing all the badges in an array

angular.copy is used when you want to make a clone of object and not update the existing object and the clone's change are not reflected in main object.

If you just want to maintain a list of badges you can execute this block of code

like this

```
 function addBadges(){
    $scope.badgeList.push(($scope.badge);
    console.log($scope.badgeList)

    }
```

If you are refreshing the controller then obviously the variable will be reset and for such a case you need to make use of angular services.
Create a service and inside the service you need to define getter and setter method that will help in data persistence
and your bages array if saved in service will persist till the application is in foreground.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

```
function addBadges(){
     //initialize if undefined or null
     if(!$scope.badgeList){
       $scope.badgeList = [];
     }

     //Check if badge does not exists in the list
     if ($scope.badgeList.indexOf($scope.badge) === -1) {
          //Add to badge list
          $scope.badgeList.push($scope.badge);
     }
}
```